# Detect that the user has not touched the screen for a specific time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, touch

If the user has not touched the screen for a specific time, I have to do a particular action. How I can do that in Cocos2d?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could subclass your UIView and override `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`.

This method is called very early in the responder chain and allows you to detect a touch anywhere in the view.

```
 - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     UIView *result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
     ....
     return result;
 }
```

Once you detect a touch, you reset a timer, so that either a new touch event comes in before the timer fires, or the timer fires.

When the timer fires, you execute your particular action.

A similar approach can be followed by subclassing `UIWindow` and then overriding `-(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. This has the advantage of not being related to a view, but to the whole window of your app and being called even earlier in the responder chain.

```
 - (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     if ([self thisIsTheTouchIwaitedFor:event])
         [self resetWaitTimer];
     [super sendEvent:event];
 }
```

Comment: Yeah this answer is more complicated than I would have given but correct still.  Just use a timer that is turned off when a touch is detected, and turned on when the touch ends.

Answer (score 0):

just googling a bit i found [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7590-touch-event-countdown-timer.html) maybe it can help you